# How do you integrate $\int_{-3}^3e^{-x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{-3}^3e^{-x^2}dx$$

U-sub?
By Parts?

See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20e%5E-x%5E2%20dx%20from%20x%3D-3%20to%203) link.

Comment: the answer is $$\sqrt{\pi} Erf(3)$$

Comment: The antiderivative is not an elementary function. One antiderivative, which is the integral starting at 0, is a multiple of the so-called error function; in terms of that the answer is $\sqrt {\pi}erf(3)$. But that is really just restating the problem.

Comment: You got the answer from WA. What more do you want ?

Comment: @Jack As stated, an exact numerical form is not there, but...You could approximate the answer with Taylor series.

Comment: If this is part of an integral calculus class you can also resort to the well known numerical methods like Riemann sums, naturally there is error associated with such an integral.

Comment: The discussion has veered into this error function thing.  Stepping back, if I wanted an approximation, I need to focus on translating this expression into a Taylor Series?

Comment: @JackOfAll Well, there are other ways.  It really depends on the integral in question.

Answer (score 5):

By the [definition of the error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), we have

$$\sqrt\pi\operatorname{erf}(3)=\int_{-3}^{+3}e^{-t^2}\ dt$$

which has no closed form AFAIK.  In general,

$$\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\operatorname{erf}(x)=\int_0^xe^{-t^2}\ dt$$

We also have the well known Taylor series:

$$\operatorname {erf} (z)={\frac {2}{\sqrt {\pi }}}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n}z^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}}={\frac {2}{\sqrt {\pi }}}\left(z-{\frac {z^{3}}{3}}+{\frac {z^{5}}{10}}-{\frac {z^{7}}{42}}+{\frac {z^{9}}{216}}-\ \cdots \right)$$

Which approximates the error function well for small values. This comes from

$$e^{-t^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nt^{2n}}{n!}$$

and integrating term by term.

Thus, we have

$$\int_{-3}^{+3}e^{-t^2}\ dt=6\sum _{n=0}^\infty\frac {(-9)^n}{n!(2n+1)}$$

Noticing that this takes 20 or so terms to get the first few digits, we apply an [Euler transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_summation) to make it converge faster:

$$\int_{-3}^{+3}e^{-t^2}\ dt=3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac {(-9)^k}{k!(2k+1)}$$

With a list of estimated values:

Let $f(N)=6\sum _{n=0}^N\frac {(-9)^n}{n!(2n+1)}$ and $g(N)=3\sum_{n=0}^N\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac {(-9)^k}{k!(2k+1)}$

$$\begin{array}{c|c}N&f(N)&g(N)\\\hline1&-12&0\\2&36.6&2.325\\3&-67.5429&1.9288\\5&-153.6974&1.7094\\10&121.5660&1.7710\\15&-8.9029&1.7724\\20&1.9865&1.7724\\30&1.7724&1.7724\end{array}$$

At first, $f(N)$ explodes to some crazy values, reaching $-150$, but after $30$ terms of expansion, it starts to show promising signs of convergence, though it is clear the Euler transform is a far better approximation.  The Euler transform manages to get 10 digits after the decimal accurate in about $40$ terms<s>, though the original series seems to catch up by then</s>, and beyond that, my calculator fails to evaluate the sums accurately.

$I\approx1.772414696519042467788969155823691159139283869490566811689$

Comment: I think that using the expansion of $\text{erfc}(x)$ should be better for so large arguments.

Comment: Just for the fun, look at the new approximation I added to my answer.

Comment: So, in a wild coincidence, this integral just happens to match a very well known function/integral?   What if it did not?  What would have been the general strategy?

Comment: I would've just approximated using Taylor expansions as I did in the second half of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem of the evaluation of $\text{erf}(3)$ (as pointed out by Simply Beautiful Art in his/her answer), is that the argument of the error function is quite large.

For such a case, we can use $$\text{erf}(x)=1-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x\,\sqrt{\pi } }\,\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2x^2)^n}$$ Let us suppose that only $p$ terms be used for $x=3$. The successive values would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \text{erf}(3) \approx \\
 0 & 0.999976791158009 \\
 1 & 0.999978080538119 \\
 2 & 0.999977865641434 \\
 3 & 0.999977925334958 \\
 4 & 0.999977902120810 \\
 5 & 0.999977913727884 \\
 6 & 0.999977906634672 \\
 7 & 0.999977911757547 \\
 8 & 0.999977907488485 \\
 9 & 0.999977911520377 \\
 10 & 0.999977907264491
\end{array}
\right)$$ while $\text{erf}(3)=0.999977909503001$.

**Update**

Inspired by the approximation

$$\text{erf}(x) \approx \text{sgn}(x) \sqrt{1 - \exp\left(-x^2\frac{\frac{4}{\pi} + ax^2}{1 + ax^2}\right)}$$ given in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), I tried to make it more accurate using the next Padé approximant built around $x=0$.

I then propose as a slight improvement
$$\text{erf}(x) \approx \text{sgn}(x) \sqrt{1 - \exp\left(-x^2\left(1+\frac{a + bx^2}{1 + c x^2+dx^4}\right)\right)}$$ where $$a=\frac{4-\pi }{\pi }$$ $$b=-\frac{2 \left(-10080+13440 \pi -7140 \pi ^2+2000 \pi ^3-328 \pi ^4+27 \pi
   ^5\right)}{21 \pi ^2 \left(-120+120 \pi -48 \pi ^2+7 \pi ^3\right)}$$ $$c=\frac{2 \left(5040-5460 \pi +2268 \pi ^2-416 \pi ^3+27 \pi ^4\right)}{21 \pi 
   \left(-120+120 \pi -48 \pi ^2+7 \pi ^3\right)}$$ $$d=\frac{8 \left(-12600+12600 \pi -3360 \pi ^2-30 \pi ^3+73 \pi ^4\right)}{315 \pi
   ^2 \left(-120+120 \pi -48 \pi ^2+7 \pi ^3\right)}$$ which leads to a maximum error of $\approx 3\times 10^{-5}$ around $x=1.8$.

Using this last formula for $x=3$ as in the present problem, it leads to $$\text{erf}(3)=0.999976650958428$$

For sure, we could continue with the next Padé approximant  and still improve. The maximum error would be $\approx 7\times 10^{-7}$ and will give $$\text{erf}(3)=0.999977972760943$$

Comment: Ah yes, I tried to derive a similar expansion.  Do you happen to know the sketch of how to derive this?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. I got it from DLMF. No idea about how it was derived.

Comment: Hm, ok then.  Looks like some tricky u-substitution or something, but I can't reach it.

Comment: Haha, nice.  I ought to read up on Pade approximations.